# Bode function - magnitude and phase

Tags: graphing-functions, control-theory, signal-processing, transfer-theory

I have the following transfer function and I need to draw the bold plot (magnitude and phase):

G = 1/(2*(s*1E-2)*(1+s*1E-2));

$$G(s)=\frac{1}{2\cdot10^{-2}s(10^{-2}s+1)}. $$

I am having a difficult time identifying the zeros and poles for this function because of the presence of the 2 constant. My guess is this function has 2 poles : one in 2*(10^2) and another one in 10^2. Is this correct ? Can someone please help me plot this function correctly ?

PS: Sorry for the bad format of the mathematic formula, this is my first question.

EDIT : I did the plots using matlab:
[MATLAB ploted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpNQZ.png)

I need help understanding  how the magnitude plot is influenced by the 2 constant.

Comment: [Here's a mathjax tutorial :)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm having difficulty reading the transfer function.

Comment: @copper.hat  I did my best at editing the function. I cant figure out how to write 10 at the minus 2 power.

Comment: Enclose stuff in { ... }

Comment: @copper.hat thank you, it looks nice now

Comment: The 2 does not affect poles or zeros. It has a pole at $s=0$ and $s=-100$

Comment: @copper.hat ok, but the 2 must somehow influence the way I draw the magnitude and phase plots in some way

Comment: It influences the magnitude of course.

Comment: @copper.hat  My guess is that now it will not hit zero at 100, but somewhere else. Can you help me understand how it influences the magnitude more exactly ?

Comment: @copper.hat I added a picture to my post showing the plot resulted using matlab.

Comment: For example, $20 \log_{10} |G(1j)| = 20 \log_{10} | {5000 \over j (j+100)} | \approx 34$. The phase never hits $-180^\circ$.

Comment: I think I understand, but just to be sure : with the 2 constant, the magnitude plot begins at 34 dB. Will the slope still be 20 dB/dec at that time ? Because if that is so, then it will not hit 0 dB at frequency equal to 100 rad/s, but earlier.

Comment: Personally, I like to plot $\omega \to G(j\omega)$ first as a sanity check.

Comment: Well, the ${1 \over 2}$ will contribute $20 \log_{10} {1 \over 2} \approx -6dB$.

Comment: The Nyquist plot is a lot more informative (to me) for qualitative behaviour. It loses the frequency annotation unfortiunately.

Comment: Oh, so as I understand it, the initial slope will be -(20+6) dB and then at 100 it will change to -46 dB.

Comment: No. the initial slope should be -20 db/decade and then -40 db/decade. The ${ 1\over 2}$ shifts everything down by 6 dB.

Comment: Ah, now I understand it. Thank you for the answer and for your time. If you want, rewrite this in an answer so I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poles are at $s=-j\omega=0$ and at $s=-j\omega=-100$ (so $0$ and $100$, not $200$ and $100$). Each pole adds a negative -20dB/decade slope to your magnitude plot and a -90 degrees to your phase plot.

Magnitude Plot: 
Because the first pole happens at $\omega=0$, the magnitude plot will start with the -20dB/decade slope. Then, at $\omega=100$ you will add an extra -20dB/decade for a total of -40dB/decade slope after that. You can make a rough sketch of this graph ignoring for the moment the values of the y-axis. Then, you can compute the gain of the system for some random frequency (let's say $\omega=10$) and adjust up and down the plot so that your sketch passes through the computed magnitude at $\omega=10$.

Phase Plot:
The pole at 0 gives you a starting constant line at $-90^o$. The pole at 100 adds another $-90^o$. The transition from $-90^o$ to $-180^o$ roughly starts one decade earlier (at $\omega =10$) and ends one decade later (at $\omega = 1000$). Right at the pole location it goes through half the transition $-135^o$.

Comment: thank you for help